# Add empty string to first argument of parseInt

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to understand how JS currying works. While I was looking for it I found a related example:

```
var add = function (orig) {
  var inner = function (val) {
    return add(parseInt(val+'', 10) == val ? inner.captured+val : inner.captured);
  };
  inner.captured = orig;
  inner.valueOf = function () {return inner.captured;};

  return inner;
};
```

What the point to add an empty string to the first argument in a **[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** 
method? 
I think it also can be related to the [***valueOf***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Comment: Do you mean *currying*?

Comment: @epascarello yeap, sorry i made a mistake

Comment: It coerces the first argument to string. However it's unnecessary, since it will be converted to string by `parseInt` itself anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val+''` converts expression to string.

Quick test to show what's going on:

```
typeof(1)
"number" // value is 1 (number)
typeof(1+'')
"string" // now value is "1" (a string)
```

> what is the purpose of making it a string?

The purpose could be to avoid native code to call abstract `ToString` method to convert first argument of `parseInt` to string.

We can read in MDN that first argument to `parseInt` is string with following description:

> The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to
>   a string (using the ToString abstract operation). Leading whitespace
>   in the string is ignored.

Comment: But what is the purpose of making it a string for parseInt?

Comment: I see, clear enough for me Thanks! Quite interesting moment

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit (First this is not a typescript question) Second, I was getting the answerer to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To explain we can re-write part of the code:

```
return add(parseInt(val+'', 10) == val ? inner.captured+val : inner.captured);

// could be written like:

if ( parseInt(val+'', 10) == val ) {
    return inner.captured+val 
}
else {
    return inner.captured;
}

// Looking at:
parseInt(val+'', 10) == val
// we're checking if the number at base 10 is equal to itself
// parseInt takes a string as it's first parameter, hence 
// the type-casting with +''.
// This step could probably be ignored as the docs say that the number is
// cast to a string automatically, however for completeness we might
// choose to manually cast it.
```

[parseInt docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Thanks for explanation!